# Repository Pattern with Linq to SQL in WebFormsMVP

Tags: linq-to-sql, repository-pattern, webformsmvp

Are there any good examples / Samples to implement **Repository Pattern with Linq to SQL** in **WebFormsMVP**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the sample solution on CodePlex [WebformsMvp v1.3.0.0](http://webformsmvp.codeplex.com/releases/view/72420)

They use a repository pattern with L2SQL.